# How to manage time in selenium script to execute same script on different server

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm automating functionality of My web project . I've created one test suit using selenium Webdriver which is working fine on Local Server(created on same). But while I do execute the same on Azure server(obviously slow as compared to local environment), The script get failed and I need to debug the whole script and need to put some wait where its taking time to locate the element. And after all changes on azure server some time it failed on local server too.

How to deal with slow website response ?

**Is there any effective way of scripting which required less effort to execute the script on different environment ?**

Answer (score 0):

You can set Implicit wait (less desired) or Explicit waits.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("your xpath")).Click();
```

In this case, you're 'telling' Selenium to wait the specified timeout before it will search the element you want to be found. If the element was not found, you will get the Timeout error.

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("your xpath")).Click();
```

In this case you're telling Selenium to get the element automatically, so in case it will not be found, you will get a `NoSuchElementException`, with no timeouts because there's no time to wait before the element to be present.

And if we're expanding it to the Explicit wait:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver();
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1000));
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("your xpath"))).Click();
```

In this case you're telling Selenium to keep searching for the element until it is found but no longer than the maximum timeout specified as a param to `WebDriverWait`.

Let's take for example the case where on your local environment a page loads on 1 minute and on Azure it takes 10 minutes (far stretched example), if you're going ahead with the Explicit wait, then you could set the timeout to let's say 11 minutes.
Those 11 minutes are the maximum timeout in which Selenium is polling for a specific element to be found. However, if you run your tests on the local environment and the element is found in 30 seconds, then your test will continue with the execution. It will not wait for the maximum timeout to complete before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely not time to locate the element, it's probably the speed of pages loading. Use `WebDriverWait`s for page transitions and any dynamic page changes. Once you wait for an element or dynamic section of the page to load, you can interact with the page without having to worry about speed. That will probably take care of most of your issues but without more specifics, it's hard to say what else might be going on.

Comment: Created whole suit on One server and  I'm not aware of which element will takes more time to get visible on other server(because whole suit working fine here). For that definitely I need to run My suit on that server and analyze the places which causing script failure and need to handle by put some Explicit Wait for those elements or any other. So my concern is, can I do something that I doesn't require my extra effort to debug the script on different servers  ?

Comment: In My case, After Submit one form there is one notification message displays. and I'm doing other actions on the basis of that message. So on local server every thing fine (working constantly) but on azure server It take more time to submit the form and getting the message. so causing problem. I am already using 'ImplicitWait'

Comment: After modifying my script by running on all server -what I done is, implemented `Explicit wait` where it causing failure and Its working fine now on all server. So again my question is,  How do i have to analyze where to put correct wait because it causing problem on other server and what I done on local server was fine ?

Comment: With experience you may be able to spot areas that might need a wait but generally you would just run it a few times and put waits where they are needed. NOTE: Make sure you aren't using both implicit and explicit waits... that will cause odd wait times.